# Dynamic row expansion in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dynamic, row, rdd

Say in my code I have a static construct mapping a Spark RDD element into something:

```
val btRdd = rdd.map {
    case Row (
        field1: String,
        field2: String,
        field3: String,
        field4: String,
        field5: Double
    ) =>
```

How to make it dynamic so I can handle RDD of any arbitrary structure in terms of number and type of input fields?

Comment: So you need to create new types depending of the schema of your dataset?. Scala indeed allows to do that because it has some meta-programming features. But if you want to create a more static typed types see https://typelevel.org/frameless/. Take a look to this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BfaBeT0pRe0

Comment: My use case is: given the dataframes of somewhat similar structure insert it into another datasources/tables. I prefer not to hard code each use case inside Row() and rather have some generic approach where I have a single class which accepts these varying RDDs, parameterized by input schema.

Comment: Maybe it could be modeled with shapeless: Using LabelledGeneric to represent the schema and merging with a specific Row and creating a new Row.